# VTK: Initiate List or Array of 3x3 matrices

Tags: vtk

The title said it all, can I make a list or array of 3x3 matrices? if so, how? I have tried using `vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArrayTemplate<vtkMatrix3x3>> inV = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArrayTemplate<vtkMatrix3x3>>::New();`.Then it gives me error like below,

```
1>c:\vtk\src\common\core\vtkTypedDataArray.h(68): error C2027: use of undefined type 'vtkTypeTraits<T>'
1>with
1>[
1>      T=vtkMatrix3x3
1>]
1>c:\vtk\src\common\core\vtkTypeTemplate.h(38) : see reference to class template instantiation 'vtkTypedDataArray<Scalar>' being compiled
1>with
1>[
1>      Scalar=vtkMatrix3x3
1>]
1>C:\vtk\src\Common\Core\vtkDataArrayTemplate.h(35) : see reference to class template instantiation 'vtkTypeTemplate<ThisT,BaseT>' being compiled
1>with
1>[
1>      ThisT=vtkDataArrayTemplate<vtkMatrix3x3>,
1>      BaseT=vtkTypedDataArray<vtkMatrix3x3>
1>]
1>C:\vtk\src\Common\Core\vtkSmartPointer.h(117) : see reference to class template instantiation 'vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>' being compiled
1>with
1>[
1>      T=vtkMatrix3x3
1>]
1>C:\vtk\src\Common\Core\vtkSmartPointer.h(116) : while compiling class template member function 'vtkSmartPointer<T> vtkSmartPointer<T>::New(void)'
1>with
1>[
1>      T=vtkDataArrayTemplate<vtkMatrix3x3>
1>]
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can achieve that using combination of C++ and VTK.

`vtkMatrix3x3 **mat = new vtkMatrix3x3*[src_obj->getObject()->GetNumberOfCells()];`

Any better approach will be marked as correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that when you want to create a `vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>`, it involves creating the following classes:
`vtkTypeTraits<T>`, and `vtkTypedDataArray<T>`, and those 2 classes expect a **scalar** as template parameter T.
You are giving it a Matrix of 9 values, so it can't work.

The `vtkDataArrayTemplate` class is mainly designed to contain scalars.

You can create an array of `vtkMatrix3x3` more easily by using for example an `std::vector` :

```
std::vector<vtkMatrix3x3> inV;
```